# how to keep footer at the bottom of content and stick at the bottom on viewport

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

I'm using bootstrap 4.5 for my Django project. I want my footer to be:

**1- at the bottom of the content if contents are larger than viewheight**

**2- at the bottom of the viewport if the contents are smaller than viewheight**

exactly as this:

[image]

here is what I have tried so far based on SO answers to similar questions,

is `base.html`:

```
<style>
#page-container {
    position: relative;
}

#content-wrap {
     padding-bottom: 2.5rem;   /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<body style="position:relative;">

        <div id="page-container">

            <div id="content-wrap">
              <!-- all other page content -->
              {% include 'partials/_navbar.html' %}

              <div >
                {% block content %}  {% endblock %}
              </div>

            </div>

            {% include 'partials/_footer.html' %}
        </div>

</body>
```

in  `_footer.html`

```
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue-grey lighten-5 mt-auto" id="footer" >
    ....
</footer>
```

but the result is either the first image(left) or it gets sticky to the bottom of the page no matter how much tall contents get.

Comment: your image are used in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071640/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually its from [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/)

Comment: I meant that you will find your solution there since the issue is the same illustrated with the same image (before you argue the duplicate is not suitable ...)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot a little thing which is `min-height: 100vh;`, it's necessary if the content are smaller than the viewport:

```
#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Check the following snippet, I've just added `min-height: 100vh;`;

```css
#page-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
     padding-bottom: 2.5rem;   /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body style="position:relative;">

        <div id="page-container">

            <div id="content-wrap">
              <!-- all other page content -->
              {% include 'partials/_navbar.html' %}

              <div >
                {% block content %}  {% endblock %}
              </div>

            </div>

            <footer class="page-footer font-small blue-grey lighten-5 mt-auto" id="footer" >
 FOOTER
</footer>
        </div>

</body>
```

And here is a longer content:

```css
#page-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
     padding-bottom: 2.5rem;   /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body style="position:relative;">

        <div id="page-container">

            <div id="content-wrap">
              <!-- all other page content -->
            

              <div style="height: 1000px;background: green">
                
              </div>

            </div>

            <footer class="page-footer font-small blue-grey lighten-5 mt-auto" id="footer" >
 FOOTER
</footer>
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: didnt help! with `#footer { position: absolute; }` it puts the footer on top of screen, with `position: relative;` it is still like the first image.

Comment: Temani Afif answer helped me. Thanks